# Cluster distances like the matlab cluster function in opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, hierarchical-clustering

I have a matlab code which need to convert to opencv. I convert almost all of the code but stuck in two line. code below is the matlab code.

```
distances=pdist(matchLocations);
tree=linkage(distances);
clusters=cluster(tree,'cutoff',Th_Clustering,'depth',depth);
```

I compute the distances and save it in a Mat object. but don't know how to cluster them. I've read documentation about `hierarchicalClustering`  but can't understand how to use it to get the result as I need. 
can you give me example or suggestion about how to cluster distances as the matlab code did?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: might be interesting for anyone http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/cluster.html?searchHighlight=cluster

Comment: If you have a `std::vector<Locations>`, then you can use `cv::partition`, with an appropriate lambda, or functor. You can see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33834092/5008845). The idea is that using the _cutoff_ is basically similar to using a flat clustering, with an appropriate threshold on the distances. I followed exactly this approach for this exact problem, and results where pretty good

Comment: @Miki I us `cv::partition` .  although it's not the exact answer and it's time consuming, It's the best answer found so far. If you write the suggested answer, I can accept your answer as the best solution. Thanks