# Python : Almost connected component labeling

Tags: python, opencv, label, blob

I have a set of binary images containing blobs. I want to label them, but some are very close (even if they don't share pixels), so I want them to share the same label.

The solution I wanted to apply was this one : http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/09/07/almost-connected-component-labeling/

It is just a simple labelling, dilation and relabelling. The problem is that it is done on Matlab and I want it to run on Python.

Do you know how to do it on Python ? I know I can use OpenCV, but the problem is how to perform the labelling of the first image after I have dilated and labelled it. :(

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You can use `cv::partition` to cluster pixel that are within a given distance. So you can put in the same _component_ both connected pixels and _nearby_ pixels. [Here's an answer with the C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33834092/5008845). The function should be available in Python also.

Answer (score 0):

Your dilated and labelled image has values other than 0 for each component (0 is background).

Your first image has binary values (i guess 0 and 255 if the image is in greyscale).

Then you only need to do a [bitwise and](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) to get the numbers of the labels in the first image

```
result = cv2.bitwise_and(labeledImage, binaryInitialImage)
```

Then you can use random colors for each label and create a new image with the colors.

Also, I would recommend to take a look to the kmeans, it may help you achieve your goal too.